# Area Between $\log(x)$ And $(\log(x))^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area, curves

This is a homework question. Find the area of the figure bounded by the curves $y=\log(x)$ and $y=(\log x)^2$ . I tried to plot a rough graph of the given curves and found that the graph of the first function came from $-\infty$ to $x=1$ and rose up in the first quadrant thereafter . Similarly for the second curve , it's graph descend from $+\infty$ to $x=1$ and after meeting the first curve at the point $(e,1)$ from below rose up in the first quadrant always remaining upside $y=\log(x)$.
I found the 3 different areas and added them up and got the answer as $6-e$ sq. units but according to my book the answer is $3-e$ sq. units. 
Any help would be highly appreciated .

[image]Thanks.

Comment: The work you did in your sum of the areas would be quite helpful in determining how best to aid you with your question...

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+of+y%3D%28ln+%28x%29%29+and+y%3D%28ln+%28x%29%29%5E2

Comment: The area between the $y$-axis and the curves is not bounded by the curves, so, if I'm understanding the original question correctly, you just want the area between $x=1$ and $x=e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include the area between x=0 to x=1 that is the area bound by the two curves with x=0. Therefore the remaining area from x=1 to x=e is 3-e.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^1\left( \log(x)^2 - \log(x)\right) dx = 3$

$\int_1^e \left(\log(x)- \log(x)^2\right) dx = 3 - e$

[image]